# How do I make a list comparison be case insensitive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

```
current_ids = ['mason' , 'chase' , 'erin' , 'guillermo' , 'george']
new_ids = ['sara' , 'gregory' , 'ChaSe' , 'josh' , 'Erin']
for new in new_ids:
    if new.lower() in current_ids:
        print("This ID is already taken. Choose another one.")
    else:
        print("You aight man this ID is gucci")
```

I am trying to make it so that the loop checks to see if the new ids are already used and if they are then it prints out that the ID is already in use. The thing is that "Erin" and "erin" are not the same according to python. I'm wondering what I need to add in order for both lists to be in the same case. For example for both curent_ids and new_ids to be both in lowercase.

Comment: What output do you get when you run this code? It looks fine to me. Also, it would be much more efficient if `current_ids` is a set, i.e. `current_ids = {'mason' , 'chase' , 'erin' , 'guillermo' , 'george'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've given seems to work, but I'm going to assume that `current_ids` may have a mixture of upper/lower case.

What you could do is convert every string in current_ids to lower case by using a list comprehension:

```
current_ids = [i.lower() for i in current_ids]
```

This creates a new list of every word in `current_ids` all lower case.

Then, you can compare as you are doing now (`if new.lower() in current_ids`)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've seen this line of code around but it was always compared to other types of code so I didn't know if it was the right one for me and you actually made my code work exactly the way that I wanted it to.